# How to connect 2 docker compontens within the same docker-compose.yaml

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, memgraphdb

I am new to the docker world and I have some issues regarding how to connect 2 docker services tougher.

I am using https://memgraph.com/ as my database and when I am running it locally I am running it like this

> docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform

I wrote my program which is going to connect to the database using mgclient and when I am running it locally everything is working fine.

Now I am trying to put in inside the docker container and running it using docker-compose.yaml

**My docker-compose.yaml is:**

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.1.0
    container_name: memgraph_container
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "3000:3000"
  my_app:
    image: memgraph_docker
    container_name: something
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: python main.py
```

and when I am trying to run it with this command:

> docker-compose up

I am getting an error regarding the connection to the server. Could anyone tell me what I am missing regarding the docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: According to docker-compose nothing is wrong

Comment: That seems fine; the `container_name:` settings are unnecessary and you probably shouldn't need to override your application's `command:`, but networking-wise there's nothing specifically wrong with it.  What's the actual error?  How is the application connecting to the database?  Have you read background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation?

Answer (score 2):

How does your `my_app` connect to the database?

Are you using a connection string of the form `localhost:7687` (or perhaps `localhost:3000`)? This would work locally because you are publishing (`--publish=7687:7687 --publish=3000:3000`) the container's ports `7687` and `3000` to the host port's (using the same ports).

> **NOTE** You can remap ports when your `docker run`. For example, you could `--publish=9999:7686` and then you would need to use port `9999` on your localhost to access the container's port `7687`.

When you combine the 2 containers using Docker Compose, each container is given a name that matches the service name. In this case, your Memgraph database is called `memgraph` (matching the `service` name).

Using Docker Compose, `localhost` takes on a different mean. From `my_app`, `localhost` is `my_app`. So, using `localhost` under Docker Compose, `my_app` would try connecting to itself **not** the database.

Under Docker Compose, for `my_app` (the name for your app), you need to refer to Memgraph by its service name (`memgraph`). The ports will be unchanged as both `7687` and `3000` (whichever is correct).

> **NOTE** The `ports` statement in your Docker Compose config is possibly redundant **unless* you want to be able to access the database from your (local)host (which you may for debugging). From a best practice standpoint, once `my_app` is able to access the database correctly, you don't need to expose the database's ports to the host.

###### Update

It is good practice to externalize configuration (from your app). So that you can configure your app dynamically. An easy way to do this is to use environment variables.

For example:

`main.py`:

```py
import os


conn = connect(
    host=os.getenv("HOST"),
    port=os.getenv("PORT"),
)
```

Then, when you run under e.g. Docker, you need to set these values:

```sh
docker run ... --env=HOST="localhost" --env=PORT="7687" ...
```

And under Docker Compose, you can:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  memgraph:
    image: memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.1.0
    container_name: memgraph_container
    restart: unless-stopped

  my_app:
    image: memgraph_docker
    container_name: something
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: python main.py
    environment:
      HOST: memgraph
      PORT: 7687
```

Comment: Ok so I'm a bit confuse because I am new to docker but when you said `Under Docker Compose, for my_app (the name for your app), you need to refer to Memgraph by its service name (memgraph). The ports will be unchanged as both 7687 and 3000 (whichever is correct).` this so far as I understand means basically to write     `hostname: "memgraph"` under my_app? Because if so, it is still not working

Comment: How does your app connect to Memgraph when it works correctly on your host? There must be some form of so-called connection string and I assume it's currently set to something like `localhost`, `localhost:7687` or `127.0.0.1:7687`?

Comment: And if I will need to use other localhost, I need to write something custom when I am calling my scrip from docker? I mean I was guessing the at the moment when I am writing 'docker-compose up' I will start the exectuion of my application, or do I need to do this just to start everything and after that I have to do 'docker run MY_APP -h SOMETHING -p SOME_PORT'?

Comment: regarding about the connection `conn = connect(host=host, port=port)` where host is `127.0.0.1` and port is `7687`

Comment: According to the Memgraph [docs](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/methods/building-applications/python), you probably have something like `connection = mgclient.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)`, right?

Comment: this is by default, I didn't custom here

Comment: yes, exactly, this is it

Comment: Exactly.... So, when you run using Docker Compose, you can't use `127.0.0.1`. That corresponds to localhost but that's not the name of Memgraph under Docker Compose. Its name will be `memgraph`. So you need to ensure `host` value is `memgraph`

Comment: oh, right, now I get it. I will test it right away, give me few moments

Comment: I did that and is still not working. So if I get it correctly I should just replace the localhost with the memgraph, which if this is the case I use this command `docker run memgraphproject_my_app python main.py network "www.googl.com" --host memgraph` which it has my `memgraph` as hostname but is still not working.

Comment: No. Your question said that you want to run this under Docker Compose. When you use Docker Compose, you run `docker-compose up` (not `docker run`).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand but... when I am running docker-compose.yaml I am just going to build my_app. And when I will run it afterwards will be with docker run my_docker_app, or not?

Comment: or if not, how can I run it via docker compose but with the ability to run different parameters at each run? so for example if in my local machine I can say `python main.py COMMAND_1 PARAMETER` and also `python main.py COMMAND_2 PARAMETER` how can I do that in docker compose?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do as I've tried to explain it above, I want to run docker-compose in order to start the server and also in order to create my image. After that I want to run different command with my image

Comment: I think I've answered your question and that you would benefit from reading Docker's documentation. Good luck!